# Can I access my own iPhone's live location feed?

Tags: iphone, ios, location

Apple's Find My Friends and Find My Phone apps have constant access to my phone's location. Can I access that somehow?

I know there are ways of getting a history of where I've been, but I'm looking for live information about where I am **right now**. Find My Phone has location data in a web app, so is there a phone-to-web sort of feed somewhere?

Comment: Have you looked at Core Location in the documentation?

Comment: I assumed that would only give me access to my phone's location within an app on my own phone, but wouldn't give me constant location info that could be accessed away from my phone via the web. Am I wrong in that assumption? If so hooray!